# Redirect to https schema asp.net mvc web api request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api2

Some web sites are sending request to https url adress. I am entering `http:/somesite.com` but it is going to `https:/somesite.com`

I am plannig to get an SSL sertificate and use https for my site. I am using asp.net mvc web api.

I want to redirect to https page my users. Should I do it with a handler, or HttpMessageHandler or directly from IIS?

Answer (score 1):

trailmax has a pretty good solution for your problem in his blog. He even has some nice unit tests:)
http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/implemnting-https-everywhere-in-asp-net-mvc-application/